# Regex Expression - L.LL.#

Tags: c#, regex

I like to create regex expression that would check a string to make sure it starts with:

```
L.LL.#
```

Anything after this first number is an irrelevance.  Is regex the best approach to solving this problem?

Note:
The L implies a letter and the # implies any number.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the *best* approach, but it'll works very well.

Comment: "Best" depends on your use-case, your data and your personal preferences. Did you try it out and have difficulties with it?

Comment: @maccettura For that you'd need `data.StartsWith("L.LL.L") && char.IsDigit(data[6])`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yeah Thomas' answer made me realize that its not the literal `#` character but an actual number.  I axed my comment

Comment: Some good ideas - thanks for that, I think I've given a bad steer here through, # implies any number and L implies any letter.

Comment: @Peter LOL, you should be a little bit more specific :) Does the dot mean something else too?

Comment: Which makes this question 1. unclear (reason to close it) and 2. not helpful (reason to downvote). Furthermore we can´t see much own affords here (which is the second reason to downvote).

Comment: Look at the [character classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions). Letters and digits are represented, but not as `L` or `#`, and making up your own notation makes things really confusing. (And is `#` a *digit* or *any sequence of digits*?)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I believe it's one digit because he said _"Anything after this first number is an irrelevance"_.

Comment: Rather than speculation, let's wait for Op to update his question to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[a-zA-Z]\\.[a-zA-Z]{2}\\.\\d")`

Assuming `L` represents a letter in the range `A-Z` or `a-Z`

Comment: @maccettura No, since # represents a digit here

Comment: Ah didnt catch that.  Thought it was just literally the `#` symbol

Comment: @ThomasAyoub and how do you know that # is a digit?

Comment: Does it matter that a digit is in it? Op has not indicated that they are going to capture the value or use it, they purely want to know if it starts with text. Hence, `string.StartsWith("L.LL.")`

Comment: *Anything after this first number is an irrelevance* @ThierryV, plus, in some cultures, `#` is used as a shortcut to *number*

Comment: @ColinM unless its supposed to validate `L.LL.1` and not `L.LL.A`

Comment: @Thomas Ayoub Forgot to match the other period as well.   `^L\\.LL\\.\\d`

Comment: @MatthewMerlene now it does. Thx